# R: filter() based on a column named from a list?

Tags: r, filter

How does one use `filter()` with a column name from a list?

I thought the following would work, but it does not:

```
filter(dt, myColList[1] == "entry")
```

^^ where: `myColList <- c("col1", "col2", "col3")`

NB: `filter(dt, col1 == "entry")` works fine, but this is going to be in a function and I'd like to feed specific column names..

Comment: It's helpful if you can make this a [reproducible question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example). That includes a representative sample of data, and all the code necessary to get the issue. Where are you getting `filter` from? `dplyr`?

Answer (score 2):

We can use `sym` to convert it to symbol and then do the evaluation (`!!`)

```
library(tidyverse)
dt %>%
   filter( !! rlang::sym(myColList[1]) == "entry")
```

---

or use `filter_at` which can take a string as input variable

```
dt %>% 
   filter_at(vars(myColList[1]), all_vars(.== 'entry'))
```

---

As a reproducible example

```
myColList <- names(iris)[1:3]
data(iris)
iris %>%
    filter(!! rlang::sym(myColList[1]) > 5)

iris %>% 
    filter_at(vars(myColList[1]), all_vars(. > 5))
```